# Для чего options.php в form action?

Tags: php, wordpress

Когда нужно указывать в форме options.php ?
В каких случаях это нужно делать?
Допустим я создаю плагин с отдельной страницей настроек в меню "Инструменты".
Нужно ли в форме настроек указывать options.php ?
т.е. в атрибуте action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывать нужно всегда, потому что именно файл options.php в составе ядра WordPress отвечает за обработку пользовательской формы настроек.

Хорошее руководство по созданию страниц настроек [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html).

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, а функция register_setting должна вызываться только тогда, если создаётся опция в главном меню "Настройки"?
Допустим я делаю отдельную страницу настроек в "Инструменты":
`add_submenu_page( 'tools.php' ...` , нужно ли здесь вызывать функцию register_setting ? По приведённой ссылке про это ничего нет

Comment: С add_submenu_page все проще. Вот пример http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/create-custom-add_menu_page-with-add_submenu_page-admin-panel/